# Creating a table from a text file and adding a column

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, input, output

I'm having some trouble adding certain values from a table created on Python.
My text file looks like:

```
E5345,22/09/2015,C106,815,A,400
E5348,23/09/2015,C109,370,A,200
E5349,25/09/2015,C110,480,A,250
E5353,28/09/2015,C114,272,A,200
E5363,01/10/2015,C124,930,A,500
E5364,02/10/2015,C125,915,A,800
E5365,02/10/2015,C126,1486,A,1486
E5366,03/10/2015,C127,576,E,0
E5367,03/10/2015,C128,427,A,350
E5373,10/10/2015,C134,1023,A,550
```

I wish to create a table on python using these values and create another column, titled Outstanding Amount. I've managed to do this, but I would like to find the total sum of the outstanding. This is found by doing the fourth column (`finaltotal`) subtract the sixth column. (`amountpaid`).
My code so far is:

```
headers = ["| Estimate Number", "| Date", "| Customer Number", "| Final Total", "| Status", "| Amount Paid", "| Outstanding Amount"]
print("    ".join(headers))
print ("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
data = open("paintingJobs.txt", "r")
info=data.readlines()
data.close()
for li in info:
        line = li.strip().split(",")
        status=line[4]
        finaltotal=int(line[3])
        amountpaid=int(line[5])
        subtotal = int(line[3]) - int(line[5])
        outstanding = (finaltotal) - (amountpaid)
        line.append(str(subtotal))
        if (amountpaid) < (finaltotal) and status == "A":
                for i, word in enumerate(line):
                    print(word.ljust(len(headers[i - (i > 20)])), end="     " * ((i - (i > 20)) != len(headers) - 1))
                print()
                print ("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    print ("\nThe total revenue is")
```

My ideal output is:

```
| Estimate Number    | Date    | Customer Number    | Final Total    | Status    | Amount Paid    | Outstanding Amount

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5345                 22/09/2015     C106                  815               A            400               415
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5348                 23/09/2015     C109                  370               A            200               170
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5349                 25/09/2015     C110                  480               A            250               230
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5353                 28/09/2015     C114                  272               A            200               72
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5355                 29/09/2015     C116                  530               A            450               80
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5363                 01/10/2015     C124                  930               A            500               430
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5364                 02/10/2015     C125                  915               A            800               115
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5367                 03/10/2015     C128                  427               A            350               77
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E5373                 10/10/2015     C134                  1023              A            550               473
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The total outstanding is
£2062
```

The total `outstanding` is found by finding the sum of the `outstanding` amounts. Outstanding amount is found by `finaltotal` minus `amountpaid`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: I would like to find the sum of the last column (outstanding amount) and print it. It should equal 2062

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a variable outside the loop to keep track of the total.  I'm excluding people that overpay, but if you want to deduct that from the total you can remove the `if` statement.

```
total = 0
for li in info:
    ...
    outstanding = (finaltotal) - (amountpaid)
    if outstanding > 0:
         total += outstanding

print 'The total outstanding is {}'.format(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Pandas library? Suppose your initial table is in a csv file called `example.csv`. You can do this in very few steps, like so:

```
from pandas import read_csv

df = read_csv('~/Documents/example.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ["Estimate Number", "Date", "Customer Number", "Final Total", "Status", "Amount Paid"]
df['Outstanding Amount'] = df['Final Total'] - df['Amount Paid']
```

Then you have options for your output. You could output back to a csv file:

```
df.to_csv()
```

or print it:

```
table_as_text = df.to_string()
print(table_as_text)
```

which will give you:

```
Estimate Number        Date Customer Number  Final Total Status    Amount Paid  Outstanding Amount
0           E5345  22/09/2015            C106          815      A          400                 415
1           E5348  23/09/2015            C109          370      A          200                 170
2           E5349  25/09/2015            C110          480      A          250                 230
3           E5353  28/09/2015            C114          272      A          200                  72
4           E5363  01/10/2015            C124          930      A          500                 430
5           E5364  02/10/2015            C125          915      A          800                 115
6           E5365  02/10/2015            C126         1486      A         1486                   0
7           E5366  03/10/2015            C127          576      E            0                 576
8           E5367  03/10/2015            C128          427      A          350                  77
9           E5373  10/10/2015            C134         1023      A          550                 473
```

And to compute the sum, you would do:

```
outstanding_amount = df["Outstanding Amount"].sum()
print(outstanding_amount)
```

Check out http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable. Hope that helps!